# Online polling - database - jsp - servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

First off, I want to avoid the use of scriptlets and/or outside libraries.
What I'm making is an online polling system, where users can register, log in, and vote on a particular question. That vote is registered and stored in the database.
The problem I'm facing is that after I'm retrieving the polls from the Database, I don't know the best way of displaying them in a .jsp page. Again, I want to avoid the use of scriptlets.

Only an "administrator" can create/remove polls. I have a servlet that handles this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    Database db = new Database();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String question = request.getParameter("question");
    String o1 = request.getParameter("o1");
    String o2 = request.getParameter("o2");
    String o3 = request.getParameter("o3");
    String o4 = request.getParameter("o4");
    String o5 = request.getParameter("o5");

    if (question == null || o1 == null || o2 == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("new.jsp").include(request, response);
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("* Poll must have a question and at least 2 choices.");
    } else {
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        db.createPoll(id, question, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("new.jsp").include(request, response);
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Poll created.");
    }
}
```

My createPoll method from Database class:

```
    // Method for creating polls. The information is added to the database.
public void createPoll(int id, String question, String o1, String o2, String o3, String o4,
        String o5) {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\MyDB;create=true;upgrade=true");
        String query = "INSERT INTO Polls (id, question, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, question);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, o1);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, o2);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, o3);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, o4);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, o5);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
```

How I retrieve all the data from the Polls table:

```
// This method retrives all the polls in the database
// and stores them in an HashMap for further processing
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getPolls() {

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> polls = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\MyDB;create=true;upgrade=true");
        String query = "SELECT * from Polls";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            String id = String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            String question = resultSet.getString("question");
            String o1 = resultSet.getString("o1");
            String o2 = resultSet.getString("o2");
            String o3 = resultSet.getString("o3");
            String o4 = resultSet.getString("o4");
            String o5 = resultSet.getString("o5");
            polls.put(id, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(question, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5)));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
    return polls;
}
```

So at the end, I'm left with a HashMap containing all the data from Polls. I want these to be displayed in a jsp page. Question first, then all the choices as radio buttons. What is best way of achieving this?

Apologize for the long post!

Comment: As I understand it, you don't wont to use JSP scriptlets? Why? It's not good idea to generate HTML-code right in you servlet methods.

Comment: From what I understand, JSP scriptlets are bad practice, so I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: You are right, JSP scriptlets is not better way to generate HTML. But generate it from Servlet methods is even worse. JSP was created to make generate pages easier. Actually, JSP and Servlet are same thing. JSP is Servlet. They are translated into servlets at runtime.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? I know generating HTML from Servlets is also bad. I'm not doing that, only for a few lines here and there.

Comment: If you know how to use JSP, feel free to use it. But if you have much of time, you can study MVC technologies, like JSF or Spring MVC

Comment: JSTL is what  you are looking for .

Comment: *Why* are you trying to avoid "outside libraries"?

Comment: Stupid requirement :/

Comment: @BalusC I can not argue with you, because you are BalusC